# Uninstall iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud

I was playing a bit with iCloud on 10.7.2 to see how it works. I decided I do not want all my documents and data on the cloud, and then the system says that if I uncheck that option, all data will be removed from my computer! 
I do not like this at all and wonder how could I uninstall completely iCloud and have all my data safe on my mac.

PS: I would also be interested if iCloud can be used only for calendars and bookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you receive is referring iCloud's local document store.

This folder is normally not visible to the end user, and in any case it is NOT referring to removing any copies of data in `~/Documents`, `~/Desktop` and so on.

In other words, it is safe to uncheck the documents option in the iCloud control panel.